# SQL query that lists ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so this is what i have

```
CONCERT (ID_K,Name,Duration)

PROGRAM(Date,Time_it_begins,Room,ID_K)

TICKETS_SOLD(Date,Time_it_begins,Room,Price,Num_Chairs)
```

I need a SQL query which lists ID_K of all koncerts that happened in at least 5 different rooms, and number of tickets sold in these concertswith a higher price than the average price of all tickets sold

Comment: Well, you start with `SELECT` to write such a query.  And `JOIN` will probably be useful.  What have you tried?

Comment: this is what kind of query? I didn't see any query in your Question :(

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place for homework questions atleast try something you didn't even try to write a SQL query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't know why you are tagged me on your comment :(

Comment: Oeps indeed wrong name tag i will change it @RameshRajendran  geuss i need some coffee

Comment: @RaymondNijland ha ha ha! wake-up  man :p

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to run it through your data, but it looks like this should work. It will join the Program and **Tickets_Sold** tables on Date and `Time_it_begins--assuming` no concerts would have the exact same date and start times, otherwise, it might help to add ROOM to the join statement--and pull the **ID_K** for concerts that have more than 4 different room numbers and have a price higher than average--assuming that Price is the total price of tickets sold for the event and not the cost per ticket, and that Num_Chairs is like, capacity, and not number of tickets sold. Because those would be important pieces of information to mention and would require a little more math in the query.

```
select ID_K from PROGRAM
full outer join TICKETS_SOLD
on PROGRAM.date=TICKETS_SOLD.date AND 
PROGRAM.Time_it_begins=TICKETS_SOLD.Time_it_begins
where Count(Distinct Room)>4 AND price>(select AVG(price) from 
TICKETS_SOLD)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Jaywant
I'm sitting here with 1 reputation point, so I'll definitely take the help.